# Notating the components of the $\hat{\beta}$ matrix when $\hat{Y}$ is multidimensional

Tags: notation, regression

This is a question on *The Elements of Statistical Learning*. We have from the linear model $$\hat{Y} = X^{T}\hat{\beta}$$
where $\hat{Y}^{T} = \begin{bmatrix}
\hat{Y}_1 & \hat{Y}_2 & \cdots & \hat{Y}_K
\end{bmatrix}$, $X^{T} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & X_1 & X_2 & \cdots & X_p
\end{bmatrix}$. In the case where $K = 1$, the standard notation for the components of $\hat{\beta}$ is 
$$\hat{\beta} = \begin{bmatrix}
\hat{\beta}_0 \\
\hat{\beta}_1 \\ 
\vdots \\
\hat{\beta}_p \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
**Is there standard notation for the components of $\hat{\beta}$ for a general (positive integer) $K$**?

Comment: I usually see these using block matrices

Comment: @Greg - Does it really make a difference?

Comment: It's all about making sure people understand what you're writing.

Comment: @Greg - - Fixed.